# ignore formula when using isblank

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet which calculates dates based off other cells which are also dates.
Using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(K2:K1210),"",K2:K1210+12))
```

I can ensure that the cells remain blank if there is nothing in them, instead of getting the annoying 01/01/1900. However, when the cells which is "blank" contains a formula
e.g. in this example there is a formula in the K column, which causes the cells with the array formula to display the "1900" date.

Is there a way to ignore formula so that the cells stay blank?

Comment: You can try `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(K2:K1210)>1,K2:K1210+12,""))`.

Comment: Perfect @Harun24HR

Comment: @Harun24HR, consider posting your comment as a solution - to increase visibility for other users that mght have the same question.

Comment: @McMahok As it helps, you may consider accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(K2:K1210)>1,K2:K1210+12,""))
```

Another formula can be-

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(K2:K,"m/d/e;;;"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K2:K1210="",,K2:K1210+12))
```